# Problems while importing a txt file into postgres using php

Tags: php, postgresql, file-io, postgresql-copy

I am trying to import a txt/csv file into my postgres database from php using "\copy" command. I cannot use COPY instead of \copy as I need it to execute as a psql client. My code is:

```
$query = '\\'.'copy data1 FROM "data1.txt" WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS "," QUOTE AS "^"';

$result = pg_query($conn,$query);
if (!$result) {
  echo "cannot copy data\n";
} else {
  echo "SUCCESS!";
}
```

When I run this php file, I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy data1 FROM "data1.txt" WITH ...
    ^ in script.php on line 30
```

Comment: I don't know pgsql, so can't really help you with that, but I would just import it in to sqlite and then sql it over

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot run `\copy` via `pg_query()`. It is **not an SQL command**. It is a meta-command of the [**psql** client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

There you can execute:

```
\copy data1 FROM 'data1.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' QUOTE AS '^'
```

Or run the shell-command:

```
psql mydb -c "\copy data1 FROM 'data1.txt'
                WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' QUOTE AS '^'"
```

Note the quotes. Values need to be [single-quoted in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS): `'value'`.
Double-quotes are for identifiers - and are only actually needed for identifiers with upper case or illegal character or for reserved words: `"My table"`.

Comment: thanks Erwin, I tried copying as a superUser(using COPY) and it worked!

Comment: what is the difference between COPY and \COPY?

Comment: @Tim: `COPY` is the SQL command and runs on the server. `\copy` is the `psql` command that wraps `COPY` for use from the client (convenient for local files).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, but instead of using the the raw `psql` `\copy` command, decided to use the `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.stream/2` function to read the contents of the file, and `Repo.transaction/1` that executes the normal SQL `COPY` command getting the data from `STDIN` provided by the stream as described in [this blog](https://experimentingwithcode.com/using-the-postgres-copy-command-in-ecto-migrations/). I haven't tested the performance of this but i figured it would be a good addition to this answer.