# Execute COPY command in remote database using local file

Tags: sql, postgresql, remote-access, bulk-load, postgresql-copy

I'm trying to execute the Postgres `COPY` command.

```
COPY warehouse_terminal.test_table FROM 'C:\file.csv' DELIMITERS E'\t'
     CSV HEADER QUOTE E'\"' ESCAPE E'\\' NULL AS '';
```

The problem is, the db where I'm going to use this is remote, and the file "file.csv" is in my local machine in `C:\`. As a result, the file is not read.
Remote db, but local file. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`\copy` of the `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) client on your local machine, it's a wrapper for SQL `COPY` for just this purpose.

See:

- [Problems while importing a txt file into postgres using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869067/problems-while-importing-a-txt-file-into-postgres-using-php/8869206#8869206)