# How to COPY local file to remote database

Tags: postgresql, pycharm

I have remote postgresql database and a local csv file which I need to add to the database. I'm trying to do it with PyCharm.

Thus, I'm trying to copy data from a local file to a remote database.

If the database local is, then this command works:

```
COPY master_relationsextra(code, serial_number, member_type, characteristic, price_list)
FROM '/Users/name/Desktop/AUTOI.csv' with CSV HEADER delimiter ';' encoding 'ISO-8859-1';
```

But for the remote database it doesn't working.

Any advice how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007401/execute-copy-command-in-remote-database-using-local-file

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I saw that already, but I do not get how it can be done. That is way I asked new question.

Comment: Replace `COPY` with `\copy` in the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm thus I did with PyCharm's help. All queries and commands did PyCharm for me. I did it as follows:

- I connected to the remote database from PyCharm database pane
- Right click on table and then `import from file`
- Choose all rules and import

That did the trick for me.