# Handling quotes in COPY to CSV from command shell

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, psql, postgresql-copy

I am trying to run this COPY query from the command shell:

```
COPY products_273 TO '/tmp/products_199.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I know you can run queries from the command line using psql:

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -c 'SELECT * FROM mytable'
```

But how can I combine the 2? The below doesn't seem to work but I'm not sure how/if I need to escape.

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -c 'COPY products_273 TO '/tmp/products_199.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;'
```

Comment: Which "command shell", important missing detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `'` and `"`, quote query with `"`.

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -c "COPY products_273 TO '/tmp/products_199.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is (IMHO)to use a here-documant. This will also solve (almost) all your quoting problems:

```
#!bin/sh
psql -U username -d mydatabase <<OMG
  COPY products_273 TO '/tmp/products_199.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
OMG
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Assuming a UNIX(-oid) shell.</sup>

If you can't use a [*here document*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) like [@wildplasser provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192873/939860) I suggest dollar quotes for string literals *within* your SQL command. Replacing the surrounding single quotes with double quotes would turn on [variable expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) in the shell, which may have side effects if special characters are contained: `$`, `` ` `` (backquote), and `\`.

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -c 'COPY products_273 TO $$/tmp/products_199.csv$$ DELIMITER $$,$$ CSV HEADER;'
```

With full quoting in the shell (single quotes) the string is passed as is, no special meaning for any character.

If special characters in the SQL string can be ruled out or are dealt with properly, [@ferhat's simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192496/939860) will do fine.

***Or*** you can replace each single quote (`'`) *within* the fully quoted string with `'\''` - which effectively ends the quoted string, appends a literal `'` and starts a new full quote.

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -c 'COPY products_273 TO '\''/tmp/products_199.csv'\'' DELIMITER '\'','\'' CSV HEADER;'
```

Related:

- [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/1315213#1315213)

***Or*** put the SQL command in a separate file (without surrounding quotes) and use [`psql -f`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

```
psql -U username -d mydatabase -f /path/to/myfile.sql
```

---

I assume you are aware of the difference between **[`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)** (the psql meta-command) and **[`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)** (the SQL command). `\copy` reads and writes files local to the *client*, while `COPY` does the same for files on the *server*. If client and server run on the same installation, you can use either. Certain differences apply, though.

- [Problems while importing a txt file into postgres using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869067/problems-while-importing-a-txt-file-into-postgres-using-php/8869206#8869206)