# How to execute copy command from Psycopg2 on remote database connection?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, psycopg2, psql

I'm running 2 **docker** containers.

1. **Flask** app - which has file volume attached.
2. **Postgres** database which has a database volume attached.

I'm connecting to the Postgres container using **Psycopg2** from Flask app.
And I have a CSV file that I want to copy to the Postgres table. This **CSV** file is present in the volume attached to flask app. and the postgres container has no connection to this volume.

When I create a connection using `psycopg2` and create a `cursor` and execute the `copy` command on that table. It is trying to copy from the folder that I have in Postgres container.

I tried `\copy` instead of `copy` for copying the data from the client container. But I'm getting **Invalid syntax error**. I even tried `\\copy`. That didn't work either.

> Unable to process files due to exception: syntax error at or near "\"
>   LINE 1: \copy account(username,password,email) from
>   '/tmp/redshift11...

Comment: `psql mydb -c "\copy data1 FROM 'data1.txt'
                WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' QUOTE AS '^'"` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869067/problems-while-importing-a-txt-file-into-postgres-using-php/8869206#8869206

Comment: But that should be run on the terminal using `os.system()`. Correct me if I'm wrong. and I want to use `psycopg2` only for dealing with database operations.

Comment: See the link I provided the copy is pg client command not default one

Comment: That worked with `cursor.copy_expert()`. I just want to know if there will be any performance issues when using this. @LinPy

Comment: sorry I have no answer for this question

Comment: `\copy` is an internal command of psql, the interactive PostgreSQL terminal. It's a wrapper around `COPY ... FROM STDIN/TO STDOUT` that makes it possible to use local files with a remote database. That's why it was giving you an invalid syntax error.